# Failed to display on LCD when interfacing with PIC18F4520 using ASM language

Tags: pic, lcd, assembly, mplabx

The LCD constantly shows nothing even though I built program sucessfully and found no error. I tried for many times in the past days but it doesn't work.
I tried appling this code on PIC16F877 by replace some necessary instructions and it worked . Below is my code in assembly language:

```
  PROCESSOR PIC18F4520

#include <p18f4520.inc>

  CONFIG WDT=OFF
  CONFIG BOREN=OFF
  CONFIG OSC=HS
  CONFIG LVP=OFF

  CBLOCK 0x20
    COUNT, COUNT1, TEMP
  ENDC

#DEFINE RS  PORTD,0
#DEFINE RW  PORTD,1
#DEFINE E   PORTD,2

    ORG     0X000

MAIN:
    CLRF    PORTD
    CLRF    TRISD
    CALL    INIT_LCD
    MOVLW   'D'
    CALL    SEND_DATA
    GOTO    $

INIT_LCD:
    MOVLW   0X20
    CALL    SEND_CMD
    MOVLW   0X28
    CALL    SEND_CMD
    MOVLW   0X0E
    CALL    SEND_CMD
    MOVLW   0X06
    CALL    SEND_CMD
    MOVLW   0X01
    CALL    SEND_CMD
    RETURN

SEND_CMD:
    MOVWF   TEMP
    ANDLW   0XF0
    MOVWF   PORTD
    BCF     RS
    CALL    ALLOW
    SWAPF   TEMP,0
    ANDLW   0XF0
    MOVWF   PORTD
    BCF     RS
    CALL    ALLOW
    CALL    DELAY
    RETURN

ALLOW:
    BSF     E
    NOP
    BCF     E
    RETURN

SEND_DATA:
    MOVWF   TEMP
    ANDWF   0XF0
    MOVWF   PORTD
    BSF     RS
    CALL    ALLOW
    SWAPF   TEMP,0
    ANDWF   0XF0
    MOVWF   PORTD
    BSF     RS
    CALL    ALLOW
    CALL    DELAY
    RETURN

DELAY:
    MOVLW   0XFF
    MOVWF   COUNT

DEL:
    MOVLW   0XFF
    MOVWF   COUNT1
DEC:
    DECF    COUNT1,1
    BNZ     DEC
    DECFSZ  COUNT,1
    GOTO    DEL
    RETURN

    END
```

The hardward connection simulated on Proteus is below:
[image: PIC18F4520 interfacing with LCD]

Comment: So is the problem with simulated circuit in Proteus, or on a real world circuit you built? But how come you even expect it to work, because the Proteus schematic clearly omits ALL power supplies to the LCD, including the logic supply and LCD panel drive voltage. Oh and the sequence to send commands to go to 4-bit mode is also clearly wrong.

Comment: @Justme Thanks for your answer. I found some similar source on both google and Youtube which built this circuit like me so in my opinion, It can be omitted power supplies to LCD when simulating. Furthermore, I tried with a full circuit include conditions that you considered but it still didn't work. By the way, could you show me more clear about my fault in this code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can't use SEND_CMD to go into 4-bit mode, because it sends two nybbles, and the display boots into 8-bit mode, so it sees each nybble as single 8-bit commands. Since you use Proteus which most likely ignores timing, you might get away with sending the command 0X32 as the first init command. Or just to be sure, 0X33, 0X33, 0X32.

Comment: Pardon me if i'm  misunderstanding your suggestion but are you meaning I should use 8-bit instead of 4-bit mode as before?  Because the sending the command 0x32 also means initialize LCD at 8-bit mode. Meanwhile I have already sent 0X20 for LCD at the first command for 4-bit mode.

Comment: You are forgetting that the display is in 8-bit mode when it boots, so currently sending 0x20 as two nybbles makes it go out of sync. It first receives 8-bit command 0x2? which makes it go to 4-bit mode. Then the low nybble 0x0? is sent, which the display sees as first nybble of 4-bit command. So your display and code are out of sync. Sending 0x32 will send it 0x3? and 0x2? so display will be correctly expecting first nybble.

Comment: I got your idea. I adjusted my code and simulated again but nothing happened. Problem seems to be caused by another reason since I used to apply this INIT_LCD function for PIC16F877 and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initialization could be more robust.

**EDIT**

Updated with code tested in PICDEM2+.

Please try this code:

```
  list n=0,c=255,r=DEC

  PROCESSOR PIC18F4520

#include <p18f4520.inc>

  CONFIG WDT=OFF
  CONFIG BOREN=OFF
  CONFIG OSC=INTIO67
  CONFIG LVP=OFF

  CBLOCK 0x20
    TEMP
  ENDC

#IFDEF TARGET_PICDEM2_PLUS

#DEFINE RS_MASK   0X10
#DEFINE RW_MASK   0X20
#DEFINE E_MASK    0X40
#DEFINE PWR_MASK  0X80
#DEFINE DATA_MASK 0X0F

#ELSE

#DEFINE RS_MASK   0X01
#DEFINE RW_MASK   0X02
#DEFINE E_MASK    0X04
#DEFINE DATA_MASK 0XF0

#ENDIF

    ORG     0X000

MAIN:
    CLRF    PORTD
    CLRF    TRISD
    CALL    INIT_LCD
    MOVLW   'L'
    CALL    SEND_DATA
    MOVLW   'C'
    CALL    SEND_DATA
    MOVLW   'D'
    CALL    SEND_DATA
    MOVLW   ' '
    CALL    SEND_DATA
    MOVLW   'T'
    CALL    SEND_DATA
    MOVLW   'e'
    CALL    SEND_DATA
    MOVLW   's'
    CALL    SEND_DATA
    MOVLW   't'
    CALL    SEND_DATA
    MOVLW   ' '
    CALL    SEND_DATA
    MOVLW   '1'
    CALL    SEND_DATA
    GOTO    $

INIT_LCD:
; Wait for 15 milliseconds after power on
#IFDEF PWR_MASK
    MOVLW   PWR_MASK
    MOVWF   PORTD
#ENDIF
    CLRF    TEMP
    MOVLW   0
POR_WAIT:
    ADDLW   -1
    BTFSC   STATUS,C
    BRA     POR_WAIT
    DECFSZ  TEMP,F
    BRA     POR_WAIT

    MOVLW   0X33
    CALL    SEND_CMD
    MOVLW   0X32
    CALL    SEND_CMD
    MOVLW   0X28
    CALL    SEND_CMD
    MOVLW   0X0E
    CALL    SEND_CMD
    MOVLW   0X06
    CALL    SEND_CMD
    MOVLW   0X01
    CALL    SEND_CMD
    RETURN

SEND_CMD:
    MOVWF   TEMP
#IF DATA_MASK == 0X0F
    SWAPF   TEMP,W
#ENDIF
    ANDLW   DATA_MASK
    CALL    ALLOW
#IF DATA_MASK == 0X0F
    MOVF    TEMP,W
#ELSE
    SWAPF   TEMP,W
#ENDIF
    ANDLW   DATA_MASK
    CALL    ALLOW
; Longest required delay after a command write is 4 milliseconds
    MOVLW   0X40
    MOVWF   TEMP
    MOVLW   0x01
CMD_WAIT:
    ADDLW   -1
    BTFSC   STATUS,C
    BRA     CMD_WAIT
    DECFSZ  TEMP,F
    BRA     CMD_WAIT
    RETURN

ALLOW:
#IFDEF PWR_MASK
    IORLW   PWR_MASK
#ENDIF
    MOVWF   PORTD
    IORLW   E_MASK
    MOVWF   PORTD
    XORLW   E_MASK
    MOVWF   PORTD
    RETURN

SEND_DATA:
    MOVWF   TEMP
#IF DATA_MASK == 0X0F
    SWAPF   TEMP,W
#ENDIF
    ANDLW   DATA_MASK
    IORLW   RS_MASK
    CALL    ALLOW
#IF DATA_MASK == 0X0F
    MOVF    TEMP,W
#ELSE
    SWAPF   TEMP,W
#ENDIF
    ANDLW   DATA_MASK
    IORLW   RS_MASK
    CALL    ALLOW
; Longest required delay after a data write is 40 microseconds
    MOVLW   0XA0
DATA_WAIT:
    ADDLW   -1
    BTFSC   STATUS,C
    BRA     DATA_WAIT
    RETURN

    END
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also tried your code but the main problem remains exist so I decided to switch to 8bit mode and got expected result.

Comment: @STUDENTSTRANGE, I have update my answer with code tested in a PICDEM2+ so I know it should work if you connected your LCD module as you have described.

Comment: thanks a million. It worked for me now.

Comment: @STUDENTSTRANGE - Since this solution worked for you, please "accept" this answer, to effectively mark the topic as solved. See "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)" from the [help]. Thanks.

Comment: please be kind and accept the answer